# Ubuntu 20.04 wifi not working Intel 6 X200

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04, iwlwifi

I updated my ubuntu today to 20.04 LTS but somehow this broke my wifi. It worked on the previous versions. I started with 19.10 and used the updater to update when new updates came out. My laptop model is the Lenovo x1 extreme gen2. It runs in dual boot with windows 10. Windows 10 has fast boot disabled and the bios boot in insecure mode.

Output from "lshw -C network"

```
*-network DISABLED
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:52:00.0
   logical name: wlp82s0
   version: 1a
   serial: 4c:1d:96:b0:19:54
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-31-generic firmware=48.4fa0041f.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:18 memory:ceb00000-ceb03fff
*-network DISABLED
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.6
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
   logical name: enp0s31f6
   version: 10
   serial: 48:2a:e3:6b:52:50
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.5-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:152 memory:cf800000-cf81ffff
*-network:0
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 2
   logical name: docker0
   serial: 02:42:c5:f1:4f:b6
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
*-network:1
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 3
   logical name: br-1a100380a996
   serial: 02:42:b0:2e:15:a7
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.18.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
*-network:2
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 4
   logical name: br-486b4eb5c7c6
   serial: 02:42:11:13:18:8b
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.21.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
*-network:3
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 5
   logical name: veth5f9e383
   serial: 0a:9b:59:6e:cc:dc
   size: 10Gbit/s
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
*-network:4
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 6
   logical name: br-49acb154db94
   serial: 02:42:8a:14:9f:c5
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.23.0.1 link=yes multicast=yes
```

Output from "rfkill list all"

```
1: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

output from "dmesg | grep iwlwifi"

```
[    2.592450] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.611144] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-50.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.611236] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-49.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.612337] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 43.2.23.17
[    2.612339] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    2.612340] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[    2.612507] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: loaded firmware version 48.4fa0041f.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.816128] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    2.829027] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    2.829311] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    3.003387] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: base HW address: 4c:1d:96:b0:19:54
[    3.501526] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0 wlp82s0: renamed from wlan0
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction of what is going wrong?

EDIT:
Fixed it by turning off and on the network managing

```
sudo nmcli networking off
sudo nmcli networking on
```

Wifi started working again after this.

Comment: gosh, it looks like on my ASUS F200CA I have to re-issue those 2 commands after every boot :-(